# Using PHP HipHop to create modular helpers

Tags: php, hiphop

From what I've read about PHP HipHop – it serves the purpose of converting PHP code into C++. The bit I did not understand is how the actual code is later on executed and whether only some elements of code can be HipHop'ed.

I have files `helpers.inc.php` (contains a lot of functions), `database.class.inc.php` (contains PDO extension) and similar that don't change often. I'd like to convert them into C++ PHP module that I could include to other project files or simply make them available across the system.

Is that possible using PHP HipHop?

Comment: Is your application the size of facebook? If not, there are many optimizations you should address before even considering something like that: namely minimizing disk I/O and database overhead. And even if you get to such a point, the benefits of HipHop over a caching mechanism like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) are likely insufficient to justify its use in your project. This sounds like a case of premature optimization :)

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil." - Donald Knuth

Comment: Well, it is certainly not as big as Facebook. : ) It is avg. 50k requests every 5 minutes throughout the day. I am not experiencing any issues with slow response either or lack of server resource. I am only curious to investigate technology around me. That said, things like minimizing I/O (server is using SSDs anyway), APC, memcached are taken care of/in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been misled and should read the [*Running HipHop* wiki page](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/running-hiphop):

> You can run HipHop in 5 different modes.
>
> **Mode 1:** Compiling HipHop and running it directly.
>
> **Mode 2:** Compiling HipHop in a temporary directory and running the compiled program from the command line.
>
> **Mode 3:** Compiling HipHop in a temporary directory and running the compiled program as a web server.
>
> **Mode 4:** Interpreting HipHop directly.
>
> **Mode 5:** Starting a Web server or daemon and interpreting HipHop on the fly.

If you want to create extensions, you should dive into the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php

But mostly, [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).

Comment: Thanks for introducing me with YAGNI. Though, see the comment I made on the original post. I am interested in learning things & I am doing that in my spare time.

Comment: We are also answering you in our spare time mate. The wiki page says that you have to run everything through HipHop, not just modules or libraries. If you want a specific piece of code to be optimized, you'll have to create a PHP extension (PECL) and write it yourself in C++. HipHop has alternatives too: http://www.php-compiler.net/benchmarks